# Collision between React-beautiful-dnd and other Dragging package

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, material-ui, react-beautiful-dnd

I am trying to use D3 parallel parcoords and Material-table together in one app.
Each component works well individual. but when those are render together an issue is occurred inside react-beautiful-dnd.
D3 parallel parcoords uses d3-dragging package inside and material-table uses react-beautiful-dnd package.

```
<div className="App">
      <Chart data={chartData} update={updateGridData} colorSet={colorSet} mouseOverRow={overRow} />
      <EditableGrid data={gridData} update={updateChartData} overRow={updateOverRow} />
</div>
```

An issue occurred is follow as.
[image: issue of react-beautiful-dnd]

I think that because react-beautiful-dnd and d3-dragging in each component are effect each other when are rendered this issue is occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I solved changing innerRef by ref on react-beautiful-dnd

Change:

```js
<Component innerRef={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps}>
```

To:

```js
<Component ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps}>
```

https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/guides/using-inner-ref.md#using-innerref